# Ayuda con laravel porfavor

Tags: php, laravel

soy nuevo en laravel, estoy haciendo un sistema de tramites, seguí unos vídeos de pagos con Paypal en laravel, el caso es que Paypal te responde satisfactoriamente si el pago se realizo correctamente, pero lo que quiero hacer es guardar una constancia de ese pago en la base de datos, como para en un futuro listarlos o como para que el usuario no pague dos veces.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public function handleApproval()
{
    if (session()->has('approvalId')) {
        $approvalId = session()->get('approvalId');

        $payment = $this->capturePayment($approvalId);

        $name = $payment->payer->name->given_name;
        $name2 = $payment->payer->name->surname;


        return redirect()
            ->route('paymentbach')
            ->withSuccess(['payment'=>"Gracias, {$name} {$name2}. Tu pago fue recibido satisfactoriamente."]);


    }
    return redirect()
        ->route('/administrador/Bachilleres/PaymentApproval')
        ->withErrors('Nosotros no pudimos capturar tu pago. Porfavor, intente nuevamente');
}
```

Porfavor ayuda, solo quisiera que me indiquen cual es la estructura que debería seguir, para hacer que se guarde en la base de datos, no se como buscarlo en la documentación de laravel :(

Comment: Paypal no funciona de ese modo, debes generar una url GET donde paypal responderá si el pago es exitoso o no y a través de esa respuesta, podrás operar tu base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

El código que tienes ya diferencia si el pago fue exitoso, eso lo hace con el if

```
if (session()->has('approvalId'))
```

El return es únicamente lo que le indicas al usuario al finalizar de procesar los datos, puedes agregar dentro del mismo if una sección para agregar información a tu base de datos (No sé como se llama tu base de datos y tu controlador así que le puse "Registro" en el siguiente ejemplo)

```
public function handleApproval()
{
    if (session()->has('approvalId')) {
        $approvalId = session()->get('approvalId');

        $payment = $this->capturePayment($approvalId);

        $name = $payment->payer->name->given_name;
        $name2 = $payment->payer->name->surname;

        /*Agregar la información del pago a la base de datos*/
        $registro = Registro::make([
            'nombre' => $name,
            'nombre2' => $name2,
            'pago' => $payment,
        ]);

        $registro->save();

        return redirect()
            ->route('paymentbach')
            ->withSuccess(['payment'=>"Gracias, {$name} {$name2}. Tu pago fue recibido satisfactoriamente."]);


    }
    return redirect()
        ->route('/administrador/Bachilleres/PaymentApproval')
        ->withErrors('Nosotros no pudimos capturar tu pago. Porfavor, intente nuevamente');
}
```

No sé que información quieras tener en tu base de datos pero por lo menos puse la misma información que hay en tu código, 2 campos de nombre y 1 campo de pago

La linea $registro = Registro::make() crea un nuevo elemento de tipo "Registro" y la linea $registro->save() guarda el registro en la base de datos

Ten en cuenta que para que esto funcione debes crear tu controlador y tu tabla